# App crashes on App Store but works in TestFlight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, app-store, testflight

I have just release an app to the App Store.

I have tested the build using TestFlight and everything worked.
After installing it from App Store it crashes upon opening.
Switching back to the same build but installed through TestFlight makes it work once again.

Does anyone know of any difference between a TestFlight version and an App Store version (of the same build), or have experienced anything similar?

The issue appears to be network related (I think, but I have very little information, and can’t setup a test env as it only happened after releasing to the App Store) and the issue is reproducible on multiple devices.

The app is a React Native (Expo build with EAS) and the source in its entirety can be found at https://github.com/pictoroma/app/

Edit: added source url

Comment: Are you using Cloudkit ?

Comment: Nope, no CloudKit

Comment: Could you get some crash log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resubmitted another build using the same source, and now everything works. Maybe something inside Apple’s pipeline corrupted the binary between TestFlight and App Store

Comment: faced the same problem. damn apples.